# Android O Error in use of IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED with notification channel in service

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I want to display notification from my service for android O but i got this crash and i want's to use IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED with notification channel

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid importance level
```

here is my code.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            try {

                  // Create the channel for the notification
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);

                    // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.instant_app_icon)
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            //  .setContentText("Instant Service")
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                    Notification notification = builder.build();
                    startForeground(1, notification);

                }

                catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid importance level at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
  at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.createNotificationChannels(INotificationManager.java:1556)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannels(NotificationManager.java:453)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager.java:441)
   at com.app.MyService.onCreate(ScreenService.java:167)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Avinash You can't use this as per document
IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED

> added in API level 24 int IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED Value signifying that
>   the user has not expressed an importance. This value is for persisting
>   preferences, **and should never be associated with an actual
>   notification**.
>   for more info you can read here
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED

Edit:
Instead you can use any other importance based on your need

- IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
- IMPORTANCE_HIGH
- IMPORTANCE_LOW
- IMPORTANCE_MAX
- IMPORTANCE_MIN

Comment: NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);
to create a channel it needs importance So how can i set unspecified.

Comment: No i dont want to display these notification on lock screen and home screen .So how can i implement IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED in this notification channel.

Comment: if your message is less important than you can set it to IMPORTANCE_LOW, FYI You can set lockscreen visibility with notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);

Answer (score 0):

According to API Docs

> added in API level 24 int IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED Value signifying that the user has not expressed an importance. This value is for persisting preferences, and should never be associated with an actual notification.

You should use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`.. 
Something like this

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

// Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

You can set lockscreen visibility with `notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);`

Comment: You can set lockscreen visibility with notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET); not working

Comment: @AvinashShinde Is notification still showing on lock screen ?